# Is peak temperature equivalent in east and west facing buildings?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun

East-facing condos/apartments are considered more valuable than west-facing condos by some due to perceived superior light quality and lower peak temperature. My assumption is total solar heat gain through east- and west-facing windows is equivalent (i.e., orientation, size, glazing are all equivalent). With this assumption, would temperature vs time plots inside each condo/apartment be equivalent (ignoring time shift)? Or could peak temperature differ?

Answer (score 0):

All the construction materials of a house cool during the night. They starts to heat when sunshines, and heats quicker than the average neighborhood, that is part in the shade. So mornings are not so cold.

On the other hand, all the neigborhood had time to heat after noon, and the sunlight is not so necessary then. It could be even too warm in the summer adding high air temperature and solar radiation.

It is the same principle of temperatures along the seasons. The extreme temperatures are normally one month after the solstices. In spite of the sunlight is maximum at the start of summer and minimum at the start of winter.